# View: Only Organic Group members, no admins

Tags: views, organic-groups

I want to generate a list of all OG-Group members by a view. (**But no admins of the group**)

I have tryed, but it dont work with members. only with admin?

Here is my exported view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'og_only_members';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'og';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'OG ONLY members';
$view->core = 0;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Defaults */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: OG membership: OG membership from User */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_membership_rel']['id'] = 'og_membership_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_membership_rel']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_membership_rel']['field'] = 'og_membership_rel';
/* Relationship: OG membership: OG Roles from membership */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_users_roles']['id'] = 'og_users_roles';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_users_roles']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_users_roles']['field'] = 'og_users_roles';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_users_roles']['relationship'] = 'og_membership_rel';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
/* Field: User: Picture */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['id'] = 'picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['field'] = 'picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: OG membership: Group ID */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['relationship'] = 'og_membership_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['default_action'] = 'not found';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['title'] = '%1 members';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['validate']['type'] = 'og';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
/* Filter criterion: OG membership: State */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['id'] = 'state';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['field'] = 'state';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['relationship'] = 'og_membership_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['state']['value'] = array(
  1 => '1',
);
/* Filter criterion: OG user roles: Role Name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['table'] = 'og_role';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['relationship'] = 'og_users_roles';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['name']['value'] = array(
  'member' => 'member',
);
$translatables['og_only_members'] = array(
  t('Defaults'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('OG membership from user'),
  t('OG Roles from OG membership'),
  t('All'),
  t('%1 members'),
);
```

---

Can please anybody help me? I've tryed a lot of options but it won't work.

Comment: I am running out of time so can not set up organic groups on local
here is clew which can help
1. all you need is to get all members of group, then remove users who have group role id set to 3
2. if you are just creating a list then probably writing the custom query would be much easier.
3. else if you want to use views, then you can filter out the results by hooking the views query and adding condition for group role != 3
4. Remember drupal user role ids and organic group role id are two different things and so far we are talking about organic group role ids.

Comment: I am in doubt if we can get the filter options with group role id basis from views ui, that will be best in that case.Once I set up I can look more options inside.